# node.js: fixing ev_ref/ev_unref warning

Tags: node.js

I have a [Node.JS extension](https://github.com/quartzjer/node-sqlite-fts) that's causing warnings in Node.JS 0.8.4:

```
WARNING: ev_ref is deprecated, use uv_ref
WARNING: ev_unref is deprecated, use uv_unref
```

I'd like to patch the extension to avoid these warnings but I can't find any information on ev_ref/uv_ref.

The warning is probably caused by lines like these:

```
  ev_ref(EV_DEFAULT_UC);
  ev_unref(EV_DEFAULT_UC);
```

(no other variants found).

What's the equivalent uv_[un]ref() call and are there any compatibility issues I should know?

Comment: as far as I know, `ev_ref()` gives the javascript thread a reference point and here's a little explanation of EV_DEFAULT_UC: http://pastebin.com/wwsWTsNC, although i'm not sure this helps.

Comment: You need to use `uv_ref((uv_handle_t *)some_handle);` where `some_handle` is a watcher. There's a bit of documentation here: http://nikhilm.github.com/uvbook/basics.html#watchers

Answer (score 0):

See [this commit](https://github.com/kashif/node-geos/commit/51aff77eb88446638b51e5030f2ad5b7bdd64af1) to node-geos for an example of how to use uv_ref() and uv_unref().